# Change location of JTextField at run-time

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Am using Java Swing.  I create one text field and a button.  If I click the button, the text field should move left by 100. How to do this?

Comment: Explain a bit more. What you want and What have you tried yet? This question is too vague.

Comment: I create one text field ,command button using swing program.if i click the command button ,the text field property will change.parameter means like this (jtext field,left,100) in command button's action performed.if I click command button ,the text field will move left by 100.

Answer (score 4):

[image: ALittleToTheLeft.java screen shot]

Converting from the spinner that moves 5px at a time, to a button that moves 100px at a time, is left as an exercise for the reader.  ;)

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

class ALittleToTheLeft {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));

                JTextField input = new JTextField(10);

                // not strictly necessary for some components,
                // but good for ones that already have a border.
                final JPanel inputContainer = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
                inputContainer.add(input);
                inputContainer.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,200,0,0));
                gui.add(inputContainer);

                SpinnerNumberModel inputAlignmentModel =
                    new SpinnerNumberModel(200,0,200,5);

                final JSpinner inputAlignment =
                    new JSpinner(inputAlignmentModel);
                inputAlignment.addChangeListener( new ChangeListener() {
                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent ce) {
                        int leftPad = ((Integer)inputAlignment.
                            getValue()).intValue();
                        int rightPad = 200-leftPad;
                        inputContainer.setBorder(
                            new EmptyBorder(0,leftPad,0,rightPad));
                    }
                });
                gui.add(inputAlignment);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: O_o  Looking for another or a better answer?

Answer (score 2):

following are different constructor for jtextfiled

- **JTextField()**
           Constructs a new TextField. JTextField(Document doc, String text, int columns)
           Constructs a new JTextField that uses the given text storage model and the given number of columns.
- **JTextField(int
  columns)**
           Constructs a new empty TextField with the specified number of columns.
- **JTextField(String text)**
           Constructs a new TextField initialized with the specified text.
- **JTextField(String text, int columns)**
           Constructs a new TextField initialized with the specified text and columns.

also **you can change different properties of jtextfield using methods** like

- setAction(Action a),
- setActionCommand(String command),
- setColumns(int columns),
- setDocument(Document doc),
- setFont(Font f),
- setHorizontalAlignment(int alignment),
- setScrollOffset(int scrollOffset)

refer [Class JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html)

**EDIT**

to move the textfield take two **class attributes x,y** and on every click change the values of x and y as you want to move, then set bounds of textfield on click of the button.as follow

```
textField.setBounds(x, y,width,height);
```

Comment: -1 for shooting blindly, but +1 as the question is not clear so your answer might help OP.

Comment: You should now update your answer as OP has asked more specific question.

Comment: The edit was not good advice.  1) This can be achieved by setting a different `EmptyBorder` to the component, no need for `setBounds()`. 2) Why `static` variables?  Did you simply mean class attributes that are visible to the button/action listener?  That would seem to be all that is needed here.

Comment: @AndrewThompson yes that is right i was just knowing the set bound to set position of a component so i mentioned that the way you specified may be better. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in construtor u can set like this

```
int x=100,y=100,width=100,height=20;              
jtextfield.setBounds(x,y,width,height)
add(jtextField);
```

Then add action performed event for button......

in the action event

```
  jTextField.setBounds(x,y+200,width,height);
  add(jtextField);
  setVisbile(true);
```

Comment: no - whatever the problem, manual sizing/locating is _not_ the solution (instead, use a suitable LayoutManager)

Comment: u can uset  setLayout(Null);

Comment: You can but it is a very bad idea that just leads to many other problems.

Comment: shaking head .. who could _upvote_ this extremely suboptimal answer? Edited to make at least my downvote effective (only excuse would be the extremely suboptimal question ;-)